# ExtJS 4 drag and drop wait for asynchronous action before deciding to complete the drop (or not)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, drag-and-drop, extjs4

Using ExtJS 4.07, I have a simple tree which loads data from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
                { id: 'centerpanel', region: 'center', layout: 'fit' },
            ]
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/getlist'
            },
            root: {
                text: 'data',
                id: '/',
                expanded: true
            }
        });

        var treelist = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            id: 'tree',
            store: store,
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            viewConfig: {
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
                },
            }
        });  

        Ext.getCmp('centerpanel').add(treelist);
    });
</script>
```

The problem is: how can I wait for a asynchronous action to complete (for example, an extjs popup or an ajax request) after you have dragged an item to another location in the same tree.

Can someone give me a hint or point me to the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually to use the beforedrop-event of the treepanel, do the asynchronous action there and return false on the event.

But there are some issues (and workarounds) which will be fixed in the next release (4.1).

The description of the issue, including the workarounds can be found here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134642-Ext.tree.ViewDDPlugin-beforedrop-event-not-working-accordingly-the-API-docs